# Problems with mapping in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping

I was going through new token example given [here](https://www.ethereum.org/token).
 I have created a below contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

    contract MyToken {
        /* This creates an array with all balances */
        mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
        function MyToken(uint256 initialSupply) public {
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 25;
        }
```

However, whenever I am creating MyToken and check the balanceOf mapping in Remix, I get the output:

```
0: uint256: 0
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Remix GUI, you have to put the address into "".